# rosserial publish sensor_msgs/Image from windows

Tags: c++, windows, image, kinect, ros

I am working on a project with windows and the sdk of the kinect v1 sensor. The goal is to send the color images from the kinect through ros,
[using rosserial.](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World)

I don't know exactly how to deal with this. Right now I am using the [sensor_msgs/Image](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) message to publish the RGB values. This is the code that I have so far:

```
    img.header.stamp = nh->now();
    img.header.frame_id = "kinect1_ref";
    img.height = height;
    img.width = width;        
    img.encoding = "rgb8";
    img.is_bigendian = false;
    img.step = width*3;

    BYTE* start = (BYTE*) lockedRect.pBits;
    img.data = new uint8_t[width*3*height];



    long it;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            const BYTE* curr = start + (x + width*y)*4;
            for(int n=0; n<3; n++){
                it = y*width*3 + x*3 + n;
                img.data[it] =  (uint8_t) curr[2-n];
            }
        }
    }   
    pub->publish(&img);
```

In the code, **img** is the sensor_msgs/Image, and  **lockedRect.pBits** is a pointer to the first byte of the image of the kinect. As far as I know, the image from kinect is stored row wise, in top-to-bottom left-to-right order, with each pixel being represented by 4 sequential bytes representing a padding byte then R, G and B.

I actually am able to send this to ros, but when I am trying to visualizate it with , I get the following error:

*Error Loading Image: OGRE EXCEPTION. Stream size does not match calculated image size in image.*

I am very stack with this, the size that I set is correct, taking into account the 3 channels for RGB. The conversion from **BYTE** to **uint8_t** should be trivial, since they are both unsigned char.

PD: I know that I can visualizate the kinect data from ubuntu and ros using openni_launch, but I need to use windows in this case due to the speech recognition engine.

PD2: cv_bridge, usually used to publish images in ros, is not included in the rosserial libraries. Therefore I have to build the image message from scratch (there could be another way?)

Any help will be really appreaciated, thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** The class of sensor_msgs/Image message generated by rosserial for windows is contains only this code:

```
  class Image : public ros::Msg{
public:
  std_msgs::Header header;
  uint32_t height;
  uint32_t width;
  char * encoding;
  uint8_t is_bigendian;
  uint32_t step;
  uint8_t data_length;
  uint8_t st_data;
  uint8_t * data;
  virtual void serialize(unsigned char *outbuffer);
  virtual void deserialize(unsigned char *inbuffer);}
```

Both the methods serialize and deserialize are not wrote here, but I actually do not know how they work.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how this compiles for you. `img.data` is an `std::vector<uint8_t>`. With that said, try this:

```
img.header.stamp = nh->now();
img.header.frame_id = "kinect1_ref";
img.height = height;
img.width = width;        
img.encoding = "rgb8";
img.is_bigendian = false;
img.step = width * 3;

BYTE* start = (BYTE*) lockedRect.pBits;
img.data.resize(img.step * height);

long it;
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        const BYTE* curr = start + (x + width*y)*4;
        for(int n=0; n<3; n++){
            it = y*width*3 + x*3 + n;
            img.data[it] =  (uint8_t) curr[2-n];
        }
    }
}   
pub->publish(&img);
```

**Update**:

I found this information about the protocol used in `rosserial_windows` limitations. Although, you are specifying the height and width and the step size, the serialization is agnostic to these message variables. I seems you have to also specify the length of the array in `data_lendth`. But here is the issue. For some odd reason the maximum array length is limited to `uint8_t`.

The array length of any array type T[] will have require the variable T_length  to be set. This means that you cannot exceed the `uint8_t` limitation without changing the protocol.

One solution but painful and slow is to split the image in 255 byte custom messages and index them. You'll have to put the image data together on the receiver side and create a sensor_msgs::Image from the data and publish that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering! It is actually defined in this way in ros. But the problem is when the pkg rosserial builds the libraries for windows, it takes only the skeleton class of the message. Therefore, in my class of "sensor_msgs/Image", the data array is defined as:     uint8_t* data. That's why I have to initialize the array in my own code. If I don't do this, it does not compile.

Comment: I see. It seems the serialization is missing some dimensions. I guess setting  the step, height and width  is not enough to serialize correctly. I see that t here are two more variables `data_length` and `st_data`. These might be the issue.

Comment: I found this information about the protocol used in [rosserial_windows limitations](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations#Arrays). Although, you are specifying the height and width and the step size, the serialization is agnostic to these message variables. I seems you have to also specify the length of the array in `data_lendth`. But here is the issue. For some odd reason the maximum array length is limited to `uint8_t`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the actual problem I guess. The uint8_t data_length definition could be due to the arduino memory limitations. But here we are not in arduino, right?. I tryied to change this definition for uint32_t in stead, but then I get errors in ubuntu when I send the message:  requested to read 4149 bytes, but buffer capacity is only 1023. These are low level configurations of the rosserial package, so I think I cannot do anything about it. I will try however to define my custom message in ros to transfer the images, although I don't know if I will have the same problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to cassinaj, I think the solution would be his proposed answer. I am going to add however some information that I found for people in the same situation.

The limitation of the arrays in rosserial is given by `uint8_t` which is a maximum of 255 bytes in most of the ros distributions. However, this issue was already commented in this [thread](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/130) where it is proposed to increase this value to `uint32_t`. The change [was done in Jade devel](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/pull/222). Therefore if you generate the **ros_lib** libraries from rosserial in Jade, the lenght of the data should be `uint32_t`. This is now the generated code for the Image message:

```
  class Image : public ros::Msg
  {
  public:
    std_msgs::Header header;
    uint32_t height;
    uint32_t width;
    const char* encoding;
    uint8_t is_bigendian;
    uint32_t step;
    uint32_t data_length;
    uint8_t st_data;
    uint8_t * data;
  Image():
    header(),
    height(0),
    width(0),
    encoding(""),
    is_bigendian(0),
    step(0),
    data_length(0), data(NULL)
{
}
 virtual int serialize(unsigned char *outbuffer) const
 virtual int deserialize(unsigned char *inbuffer)
```

I was expecting to get everything working now, but another problem appeared. Eventhough the length of the array can be a high value, the buffer of the rosserial's messages is still limited to a low value. I guess it is the protocol itself which is limited. Then, I was not able to send the whole image message which is 480x640xRGB, but I could send a portion of the image (8x8xRGB) as far as I tested. This worked finally, and I visualized the image in rviz with no problems.

Therefore, one solution would be, as cassinaj proposed, to split all the data in portions, and then put them all together in the receiver side. This should work, although it sounds really painful (if I split the image in 8x8 portions, that would be about 4800 messages for a single image!).

For this reason, I am trying to use win_ros (ros for windows), in order to send all the data from the kinect through ros itself. It's a pity that rosserial has those limitations because it is really easy to use and to implement.

If someone has anything else to add, or I am missing something, please let me know. Any help is really appreaciated!